# multi keys and many-to-many relationship

Tags: database, relationship, normalization

Lets say I have two tables teams and players and we assume that many players can be members of many teams(in different sports). Thus I have the first table 
teams with PKs both team_name and sport. the second table "players" has PK player_id. Due to the *-to-* relationship I have also a third table with all the keys (team_name, sport and player_id).

the problem in this case is that the column team name is not unique in the first table. Of course I could give another column as the id and make this one the PK. But I am not sure if this is the best approach and how this is solved in the real world. So the questions are:
1. if I can have a composite key like this which one column doesnt have unique values
2. How do you normalize it appropriately?
3. Could I use just one of the composite key in the third table if this is convenience or I always have to take the whole key?

```
create table sports(
sport varchar(30),
capt_id int references captain(capt_id),
primary key(sport)
);

Create table teams(
team varchar(30),
sport varchar(30) references sports(sport),
primary key(team,sport)
);

create table teamplayer(
player_id int references player(player_id),
sport varchar(30) references sports(sport),
team varchar(30) references teams(team),
unique (team, sport),
primary key(player_id, team, sport)
);
```

Comment: Your model is good, is usual that you have a composite PK and repeat values in both columns, but is important that doesn't exists two teams with same name in the same sport.

Comment: I can understand that. but I get  an error when I create the tables. The error is "ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "teams" "

Comment: Could you edit your answer with create table statement that you are trying?